# Icons on the desktop may slow down Mac?

Tags: icon, desktop

When I ask a question about if I run too many process will slow down my Mac for Magican measured my Mac is high CPU usage. A Mac user tell me the icons on the desktop may still influence the performance of my Mac. Is this true?

Answer (score 5):

Reputable sources like [Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/159699/2011/05/troubleshooting_speed_passwords.html) indicate that the Finder draws non-generic Desktop icons the same way it draws open windows, and the more of them there are, the more memory and processor time it takes to refresh the Desktop. I have not found any sources that indicate this is a major factor in system speed, but yes, more custom icons on the Desktop take more resources when the computer redraws the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "icons on the desktop"? Having files (docs, pictures, etc) does not slows your machine down though. Now, if you are referring to the apps on your Doc if you have a lot open and depending what apps you have it might. Widgets can slow somewhat the system. You might want to look also into upgrading your memory if your system just came with the minimum. I have a MBP and after upgrading the memory from 4 to 8 GB I saw a huge positive improvement.