# Is having too much stuff on the Desktop still a performance killer?

Tags: mac, performance, desktop

See for example

[This article](https://lifehacker.com/5893054/an-overly-cluttered-desktop-can-seriously-slow-down-your-mac--clean-it-up-for-a-noticeable-speed-boost)

[Or this one](https://www.softwarehow.com/why-mac-slow/)

[Or this one](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-shouldnt-store-files-on-the-desktop--cms-21721)

Now, the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41417/icons-on-the-desktop-may-slow-down-mac) seems to suggest that the problem is icons on the desktop needing to be repeatedly redrawn, but the articles seem to indicate that it's a problem even if you've got stuff tucked away in a folder (there's some conflict on this point in the linked articles).

So is having lots of stuff (e.g. 2700 jpgs) in a folder on the desktop a performance killer? Is it the number of files? Their size? Both? If it's not still a problem when did it stop being a problem?

I ask in part because the desktop stacks in mojave seem to be encouraging this practice, when I had always thought that the received wisdom was to not do so.

### Clarification:

Adding files to the file system should not (in theory) consume any extra system resources other than space in persistent memory (be it solid state or physical disk), with the obvious exceptions like file system journaling/integrity checks and the like, pre-emptive caching, etc. Certainly, *viewing* a bunch of files in Finder (especially with e.g. image thumbnails) will use system resources like processor/main memory/etc, but I have read (in the articles linked above) that *just having* a large number of files on the Desktop, even inside a folder where they are not being drawn to the screen, *does in fact* consume these resources (and to a large degree at that) on MacOS/OS X. More so than having the same files in a different location on the filesystem. Is this true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41417/icons-on-the-desktop-may-slow-down-mac

Comment: @GrahamMiln I believe I addressed why the question is not a duplicate (I even linked it) in my question... how does that question (or it's answers) address the case where the icons are not actually displayed on the Desktop (e.g. in a folder)?

Comment: My concern is that the question is opinion based – how slow is too slow? On what configuration – spinning drive or solid state? As is, it is difficult to answer in an Ask Different appropriate manner.

Comment: @GrahamMiln edited for clarity. Better?

Comment: I agree with GrahamMiln: this is opinion-based. Vote to close.

Comment: Just throwing in my 2¢.  The first link is vague, the second is a rehash and a source of the first and the third is quite frankly, wrong.  The QL cache is stored in `/var/folders/..../com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache/` and *not* in RAM as noted.  There's no empirical evidence presented and thus, the question is entirely based in opinion.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Allan et. al. if this question is opinion-based, why is the other one I linked not? Also, if the articles are a bunch of phooey that would actually be an answer to my question: i.e. that there's no actual evidence that storing stuff in a folder on the desktop is a problem other than some guy on lifehacker wrote an article and everybody and their brother keeps referencing it.

Comment: Just because it's written on the internet does not make it true. There is some logic behind 'a million icons splattered on my desktop makes my machine work harder', especially on a spinning rusty iron disk, but extrapolating that to include the same million files inside a single folder just has no logical basis.